# Changing some file extensions in a folder

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, batch-rename

For example, I want to change all files' extensions to jpg. I can do this with below code. But it is necessary to determine non-jpg extensions one by one. How can i do this, automatically?

```
cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\
rename *txt *.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried this one liner `@Ren "%UserProfile%\Desktop\*.*" "*.jpg"`?

Comment: Works fine, thanks but only problem that if there is a file with the same name, gives warning that "A dublicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found". Then, conflicted file is left alone. Is there a way to delete one or replace conflicting files.

Comment: That is a different question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options, either skip files that already exist, or rename files that already:

Skip files that already exist.

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("%userprofile%\desktop\*.*") do if not "%%~xi" == ".jpg" if not exist "%%~ni.jpg" rename "%%~fi" "%%~ni.jpg"
```

or replace the file if it exists:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("%userprofile%\desktop\*.*") do if not "%%~xi" == ".jpg" move /Y "%%~fi" "%%~dpni.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

After it was pointed it out I realise you might want to make all files jpg files and not just .txt files. One approach would be:

```
forfiles /M *.* /C "cmd /c if /i not @ext==\"jpg\" copy @file @fname.jpg /Y & del @file"
```

If you want to include subdirectories:

```
forfiles /S /M *.* /C "cmd /c if /i not @ext==\"jpg\" copy @file @fname.jpg /Y & del @file"
```

---

Original answer:

> In a bat file you can do this:
>
> ```
> xcopy *.txt*.jpg /Y
> del *.txt
> ```
>
> Or as a command:
>
> ```
> xcopy *.txt *.jpg /Y && del *.txt
> ```

Comment: Perhaps you completely misread the question in its entirety? This is not at all what was requested.

Comment: It's not? This will create a copy of all .txt files as .jpg files and if a .jpg file with that name already exists it will be overwritten. Then all txt files are deleted. So basically it's a rename with automatic overwrite on name conflict and that was how I understood the question.

Comment: again, it is not what was request, read the question again.

Comment: I read "rename *txt" as he wanted to rename .txt files but I've changed my answer to include all files.